# How to assign a schema extension to all queried users using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to assign an extension i created to certain user instances using the query below.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq c42b9cae-ea4f-4ab7-9717-81576235ccac)&$count=true
```

On header i gave "ConsistencyLevel" as "eventual". [Graph Explorer Link.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users%3F%24filter%3DassignedLicenses%2Fany(x%3Ax%2FskuId%20eq%20c42b9cae-ea4f-4ab7-9717-81576235ccac)%26%24count%3Dtrue&method=PATCH&version=v1.0&GraphUrl=https://graph.microsoft.com&requestBody=eyJleHRiZGR0czRqa19leHRyYXZhbHVlcyI6eyJzYW1wbGVWYWx1ZTEiOiIxMjIiLCJzYW1wbGVWYWx1ZTIiOiJOZXcgTWFuYWdlcnMiLCJzYW1wbGVWYWx1ZTMiOiJPbmxpbmUifX0=&headers=W3sibmFtZSI6IkNvbnNpc3RlbmN5TGV2ZWwiLCJ2YWx1ZSI6ImV2ZW50dWFsIn1d)

I received error below.

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Request_BadRequest",
    "message": "The following query options are not supported by this request method or cannot be applied to the requested resource: $filter,$expand,$orderby,$count,$inlinecount,$select,$skiptoken,$skip,$top",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-02-03T12:26:57",
        "request-id": "bdb51771-f2e2-4b34-99b0-708150ef5855",
        "client-request-id": "988d5bc5-c549-9147-b02d-4919e5c128c4"
    }
}
```

}

Is there any way for me to assign schema extensions on users with my existing query? And if this is possible how can i implement it in Graph Explorer and Java using ms-graph-sdk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I opened your link in the question, I got the page like screenshot below, and after change the request method to 'GET', I can successfully get response.

By the way, I found a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#odata-system-query-options) said that 'Note: OData 4.0 supports system query options in only GET operations.'

[image]

==================UPDATE=====================

I assume that you wanna add properties to a specific user, here you need to use [update user api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-update-properties-of-the-specified-user), but I found that I can't achieve it. In the API document, it mentioned that request body are included in some specific properties.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to assign extension to certain users using graph api?

Comment: You need to patch all users one by one. You can use the batch endpoints to run them in sets if that helps.